# Different color points with Torque

Tags: carto, torque

So! Really basic question. I want to make a Torque map – easy enough – but I want it to display the various datapoints in different colors depending on the value of annual_irr.

Here's what I thought I'd enter into the cartocss editor to make it work (where annual_irr is a number from -.06 to .24), but this just displays the datapoints with no color at all:

```
Map {
-torque-frame-count:512;
-torque-animation-duration:30;
-torque-time-attribute:"bldg_bought";
-torque-aggregation-function:"count(cartodb_id)";
-torque-resolution:2;
-torque-data-aggregation:cumulative;
}

#fake_porchlight_thing_for_cartodb_larger_bldgs_1{
  comp-op: lighter;
  marker-fill-opacity: 0.9;
  marker-line-color: #FFF;
  marker-line-width: 1.5;
  marker-line-opacity: 1;
  marker-type: ellipse;
  marker-width: 6;
  [ annual_irr <= 1 ] { marker-fill: #1a9850; }
  [ annual_irr <= 0.1 ] { marker-fill: #fff2cc; }
  [ annual_irr <= 0 ] { marker-fill: #d73027; }
}
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong? Why isn't the CartoDB thingy interpreting the annual_irr marker-fill rules correctly?

Answer (score 1):

You can't directly use column names in Torque's CartoCSS like you can with other types of maps. Instead, you need to let the `torque-aggregation-function` do the work for you. This function outputs a number called `value` that you can later use in the CartoCSS.

It might seem weird to do it this way, but Torque bins data in time and space and then uses the aggregation function you use in that argument to output a value. For instance, if there are four events in a bin in `num_column` that are 2,4,6, and 8, `count(num_column)` would output 4, `sum(num_column)` would output 20, `avg(num_column)` would output 5, etc. So you need to decide which aggregation function to use. They're [PostgreSQL functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-aggregate.html).

So in your case, maybe average is best? You would change `count(cartodb_id)` to `avg(annual_irr)`,

and later in the CartoCSS, change `annual_irr` to `value`, and the numbers in the conditions to something appropriate for what you would expect in a cell. Reducing the resolution to 1 means you have very small bins and your map will be closer to a normal marker-based map.

You can read more about how it works [here](https://github.com/CartoDB/torque/wiki/How-spatial-aggregation-works).

Hope that helps!